# How do you pass a global variable ($User) into javascript in Salesforce Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, user

How do you pass a global merge field type $User into javascript?

I'm able to pull the User First Name into the HTML with the below HTML, but I would like to pass the User First Name into the Javascript within Visualforce.

How would I go about doing that? I've tried the below, but I get the following error:

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: Chris is not defined
```

Chris is my name which I want it to alert me of. I've tried to turn this into a string with no luck either.

Below is what I'm trying

```
<apex:page >
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        Hello {!$User.FirstName}
    </div>

<script>
    alert(!$User.FirstName)

</script>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to surround the expression with `{! }` to let Visualforce know to evaluate the expression and output the text into the page. Then, because you want the output to be a valid JavaScript string, quotes are also needed. (Without the quotes JavaScript assumes the name is an existing variable.)

So altogether:

```
alert('{!JSENCODE($User.FirstName)}');
```

Use your browser's "View Source" or "Inspect Element" feature to check what is being output into the HTML page.

**PS** Corrected answer based on comments that JSENCODE is also needed. Avoids a JavaScript error if the string contains the same quote that is used to indicate that its a JavaScript string, and avoids the security risk of the text containing executable JavaScript.

Comment: Humbly recommend using JSENCODE() function too

Comment: Not using JSENCODE had bitten me before; that's definitely necessary for text fields.

Comment: @bigassforce and Mike Chale I've added that correction to the answer - thanks.